# Large amount of tasks, python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a function that I need to call many times, not much data is sent to the functions so I am not too worried about the pipe load. But after a while, it seems like the cpus are not working concurrently and become very slow. What is the correct way to multiprocess a function many times?

I am currently using a multiprocessing pool

```
#sessions = some list
for session in sessions:
        migrators.append(pool.apply_async(migration,(None, session,  )))

    try:
        total = 0
        for m in migrators:
            total += m.get()
    except:
        traceback.print_exception(*sys.exc_info())
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```

Comment: What is the function? What does it do? What are those arguments `(None, session)`? Are you using a Pool or a ThreadPool? Why not use the higher-level `pool.imap_unordered()`?

Comment: have you also tried setting `maxtasksperchild` in the `Pool` constructor to cleanup unmanaged resources? is the memory consumption or number of open handles continually increasing?

Comment: @AKX I am using a Pool, is there an advantage over running the process using map/imap vs manually iterating over the iterable to submit to the process pool. The function reads information from an external db (elasticsearch), and writes to a local elasticsearch instance, a postgresdb, arangodb, and s3. The params tell the process what data to migrate.

Comment: @Aaron that is a good point. I do close all my connections/resources but I will use it just in case. The amount of memory consumed stays consistent throughout the process.